# Python + Selenium: Reload a page after a timeout on WebDriverWait call

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am looking for a proper way to implement below in Python Selenium

1. Load a page
2. Wait for a certain period of time(e.g 30 secs) for a button to be clickable (by calling WebDriverWait)
3. If got TimeoutException, reload the page again, i.e. goto step 1)

```
url = 'https://...'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

try:
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,'button')))
except TimeoutException as e: 
    <reload the url again>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create function that will auto call with refresh if element is not found.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html")


def refresh():
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "button"))
        )
    except:
        driver.refresh()
        refresh()


refresh()
```

Answer (score 1):

To perform the following tasks:

1. Load a page
2. Wait for a certain period of time(e.g 30 secs) for a button to be clickable (by calling WebDriverWait)
3. If got TimeoutException, reload the page again, i.e. goto step 1)

You can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890). For the sake of demonstration, I will consider an element which is not available on [Google Search Home Page](https://www.google.com/):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  while True:
      try:
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
          WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "kokei")))
          print("Button found")
          break
      except TimeoutException:
          print("Button not found ... reloading page")
          continue
  # perform your remaining steps here on successfully finding the clickable element
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Button not found ... reloading page
  Button not found ... reloading page
  Button not found ... reloading page
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of elements with `explicit wait` with presence of elements in Dom with `button` as `class name`. If list of element is empty then you can refresh page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://...'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

if  len(wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'button'))))==0 :
  driver.refresh()
```